# Find duplicates in some columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm searching in Excel columns for duplicates. With the following formula i'm finding duplicates, if they appear in all columns i'm searching in:

`=OR(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6000;A2)>0;COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6000;A2)>0;COUNTIF($C$2:$C$6000;A2)>0;COUNTIF($D$2:$D$6000;A2)>0;COUNTIF($e$2:$e$6000;A2)>0)`

How is it possible to find duplicates, which appear not in *all*, but in *some*, at least two, columns?

Comment: So if your sheet has 4 columns of data, and you have value `123` in columns A, B, C and also D, then it's no longer a duplicate.. But if it was only in columns A, B and D then it would be a duplicate? And also, if it was only in column A but it appeared twice it would also not be a duplicate? Perhaps an example grid of data would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the booleans and test if greater than 1:

```
=(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6000;A2)>0)+(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6000;A2)>0)+(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$6000;A2)>0)+(COUNTIF($D$2:$D$6000;A2)>0)+(COUNTIF($e$2:$e$6000;A2)>0)>1
```